# curve fitting in LabView

Tags: labview

I am using curve fitting in Labview . I used nonlinear curve fitting. my function is like `a*e(-b*x)+c`.

How can I extract `a`, `b`, and `c` from this curve fitting. I want to use these coefficients in front panel but I can’t.

Answer (score 1):

The help file for the [Exponential Curve fit](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361K-01/gmath/exponential_fit/) describes the return parameters
[image]

- **amplitude** returns the amplitude of the fitted model.
- **damping** returns the damping of the fitted model.
- **offset** returns the offset of the fitted model.

And specfies them:

> This VI uses the iterative general Least Square method and the Levenberg-Marquardt method to fit data to an exponential curve of the general form described by the following equation:
>
> f = aebx + c
> where x is the input sequence X, **a is amplitude**, **b is damping**, and **c is offset**. This VI finds the values of a, b, and c that best fit the observations (X, Y).

Comment: And the help for [Nonlinear Curve Fit](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/gmath/nonlinear_curve_fit/) also describes the returned parameters, namely the `best fit parameters`. Given that you have given the function and initial parameters, you should know the order of the returned ones.